# Please Help: "Audience" usage

Tags: meaning, word-choice, questions, phrasing, christmas

I want to write "My whole life, I have been audience to a..." Does that make sense? Should I instead write "been the audience to..." or "been an audience to..." Am I using this correctly? Thank you. People commonly say "given audience to" so I feel like it should work.

Comment: What idea are you trying  to convey?

Comment: I  think “give audience to” is a formal expression.

Comment: _Give audience to_ refers to a distinguished person granting an interview, not the audience at a theatre or concert.

Comment: I think the most _idiomatic_ would be _have been audience to_.

Comment: Since an audience is multiple people, I'm not clear how you could *be an audience* on your own. Do you mean be part of the audience, or be the entire audience, or an audience of one?

Comment: You need to complete your example sentence for us to come up with the right word: *My whole life, I have been audience to a _________________.*

Comment: @Tinfoil Hat - My whole life I have been (audience/an audient) to a growing chorus of ignorance.

Comment: [*Give audience to*](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/To+give+audience) (listen) works. *My whole life I have given audience to a growing chorus of ignorance.* You could also say *I have suffered a growing chorus* or *I have endured a growing chorus*.

Answer (score 2):

Using ["*been witness to*"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be%20witness%20to) is closer to what you want to say. You can also say "*I have had to witness*" or "*I have had to watch/listent to/put up with/suffer...*"

Comment: You can witness anything. "*Chorus*" does not necessarily mean a choir, just broad and vocal agreement. I don't think it needs all other vocabulary to conform to concert hall terminology.

Comment: Yes. 'Be witness to ...' is an idiomatic verbo-nominal expression whereas 'be audience to ...' is not (though the rare example _can_ be found: [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+been+witness+to%2Chave+been+audience+to&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20witness%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20audience%20to%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20witness%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chave%20been%20audience%20to%3B%2Cc0)). Here, 'witness', 'audience' are not count usages.